# Trying to allow a normal user to run a command which requires inputting root password

Tags: linux

I have this tool which allows users to manage printers in the linux environment.
I need to allow a user to run this tool without giving him the root password.
The permissions on the tool are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       78 Dec  4  2008 system-config-printer
```

Comment: The permissions on the tool are wrong. Group others should absolutely not have write permission to a tool like this in any case, and most especially if the tool has a setuid permission set; that is an instant root-level hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a great way to achieve that goal and i will use it myself next time.
I used another method though:
i've edited /etc/group and added the user in the end of the sys line:
sys:x:3:root,bin,adm,itaig

anyways, thanks for your solution.
Itai

Answer (score 3):

The `sudo` command is very configurable, and can be used to grant specific users permission to run specific commands. Use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`, and enter a line like the following:

```
bob ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/system-config-printer
```

The user `bob` would then run `sudo /usr/sbin/system-config-printer` in order to run the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the owner and group of the executable as root, and then do `chmod u+s` and `chmod g+s` on it

Edit: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)